# What is the equivilent to Solidity's abi.encode() function in Web3 JS?

Tags: solidity, web3js, typescript

I have a function in Solidity, that I would like to replicate using Typescript and Web3

```
    function mint(
        address to,
        uint256[] memory ids,
        uint256 indexToMint
    ) public {
        require(
            registeredHashes[to][keccak256(abi.encode(to, ids))],
            "Hash not registered"
        );
    ...
```

What is the Web3js + Typescript equivilent to the line

`abi.encode(to, ids)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters`:

```js
const web3 = new Web3;
web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
  ['address', 'uint256[]'],
  ['0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f', [1, 2, 3]]
);
```

Results in:

```
0x0000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
```

[Documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameters).

Comment: Many thanks to you, this is what I was looking for